# How to only accept specific input

Tags: javascript, validation

html text input only 0 or 2 or 4 or 6 or 8 or 10 only.otherwise a blank space should be returned

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var regexExp = /[2,4,6,8]{1}|10/
  return (regexExp.test(($('#evt').val())) ? evt ').val() : false);

  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="T2" id="d1" size="5" maxlength="2" min=0 max=10 step="2" Onkeypress="return isNumberKey(this.value)">
```

Comment: Read [How to Ask a Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your title should be a **very** short summary, reflecting your issue. Your question is not very clear,  what do you expect to be returned if the input is any of the accepted values? Your function is missing brackets and is not valid code to begin with. Please only post valid code. Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as already linked previously and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, I think this is what you are looking for.
exception being that the input value of "1" is valid.

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="2" onkeypress=" let satisfy = (/^(0|2|4|6|8|1|10)$/).test(this.value + event.key); if(!satisfy){this.value = ''} return satisfy;">
```